# Identify due date excluding weekends

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am using the following formula to change a cell's conditional formatting depending on how close to today's date the value is:

Cell Value is Between `=TODAY()-5` and `=TODAY()+5`

This is working but I want to exclude weekends.

So if the date in the cell is 03/10/14 and today's date is 26/09/14 I would like to be able for my formula to identify that there are only 6 days and not 8 days which would include the weekend.

Please can someone tell me how what formula I would need to use to do this? I have tried to use the WORKDAY() function but can not seem to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your dates are in ColumnA, please try this CF formula rule:

```
=AND(A1<=WORKDAY(TODAY(),5),A1>=WORKDAY(TODAY(),-5))
```